# Airflow DAG failing with "`python_callable` param must be callable" exception using the PythonOperator

Tags: python, airflow

Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/my_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 179, in apply_defaults
result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 136, in **init**
raise AirflowException('`python_callable` param must be callable')
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: `python_callable` param must be callable

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator, PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime
from random import randint
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

def _training_model():
    return randint(1,11)


def _choose_best_model(ti):
    accuracies = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids =[
        'training_model_A'
        'training_model_B'
        'training_model_C'
    ])
    best_accuracy = max(accuracies)
    
    if (best_accuracy >8):
        return 'accurate'
    return 'inaccurate'

with DAG(
    dag_id="mobile_app_usage", start_date=datetime(2021,1,1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",catchup=False) as dag:

    training_model_A = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "training_model_A",
        python_callable=_training_model()
    )

    training_model_B = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "training_model_B",
        python_callable=_training_model()
    )

    training_model_C = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "training_model_B",
        python_callable=_training_model()
    )

    choose_best_model = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id = "choose_best_model",
        python_callable= _choose_best_model()
    )

    accurate = BashOperator(
        task_id ="accurate",
        bash_command="echo Accurate"
    
    )

    inaccurate = BashOperator(
        task_id ="inaccurate",
        bash_command="echo Inacurate"
    
    )
```

[Image of my airflow webserver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft41a.png)

Answer (score 7):

The `python_callable` parameter only needs the name of the callable to be executed instead of *actually* calling it.  Like this:

```py
...
training_model_A = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "training_model_A",
        python_callable=_training_model
    )

    training_model_B = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "training_model_B",
        python_callable=_training_model
    )

    training_model_C = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "training_model_C",
        python_callable=_training_model
    )

    choose_best_model = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id = "choose_best_model",
        python_callable= _choose_best_model
    )
...
```

FYI - In the snippet above I also updated the `task_id` argument for the task assigned as "training_model_C" since it had the same `task_id` as "training_model_B".  In Airflow the `task_id` values need to be unique within a DAG.

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciated

Comment: @AkashKumar You're welcome, glad to hear it! Could you mark this as the accepted answer and up vote for future users?